# Rational Functional Tester vb6 - Stackhash Crash on Win7

Tags: vb6, rft

Ive got an issue using RFT with VB6 on Win7 (32,64) bit. This isnt is not present on Windows XP.

I am unable to highlight objects, or call verification points as the VB6 application crashes with a stackhash error. I have done weeks of research and have tried various things(DEP, Compatibility mode, clean boots etc) but am thus far unable to isolate the issue.

It seems that certain properties, these can vary, are not available once the program has been compiled. Running the application through VB6 IDE in debug mode **does not** result in a crash. Once compiled though, the crash occurs constantly.

I have used Windbg to debug the error to see what happens, and can see that there is a call to unallocated memory, resulting in heap corruption. What causes this? Is there anyway around this?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Stackhash means the stack is so corrupted no post mortem debugging can be done. So MS hashs the stack so you can see if errors are the same.

Comment: So there in-fact nothing i can do to trace the issue? i have managed to reproduce the error on Windows XP SP3 now as well, although it seldom occurs. It does however mean, any automation is hit and miss.

Comment: You can step through your program and see where it goes haywire. It's not just heap corruption, it's a corrupted stack (parameters to functions and local variables). The firstthing to do is dump what modules are loaded. `lm` I think in WinDbg.

Comment: Problem does not occur during debug sessions. Only on compiled code.